# Qt How to update GUI QFrame with combobox selection

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a combobox that holds a list of different command types. I want to change the visible input fields on my GUI depending on the selected command in the combobox. I am very new to Qt, and I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction to implementing this.

My current idea is to have a "select" button that emits a signal, and the connected slot will grab the current index of the combobox. I THINK I need to implement a custom class to hold a QFrame. The custom class will hold slots that indicate which data inputs (for the selected command) should be displayed in the QFrame.

IE, if COMMAND_1 is selected in the combobox, 3 input fields display in the QFrame. If COMMAND_2 is selected, a pair of radio buttons is displayed in the QFrame, and those 3 input fields are hidden or deallocated.

Is this a good way of attempting to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going about it the right way.  But Qt actually makes it even easier than what you're thinking.

You can use two built-in widgets: [QComboBox](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html) and [QStackedWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html).  You're familiar with the combo box; the stacked widget is a set of widgets, of which only one will be displayed at a time.  It's essentially a tabbed widget minus the tabs.

Set up your stacked widget so that its first widget is what you want to show when your combo box is showing its first option, the second for the second, and so on.  Then you can connect a built-in signal to a built-in slot: [QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) to [QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex(int)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I will look into this! Kudos